# Excel to matlab solver equivalent

Tags: excel, matlab, matrix, solver

I am currently stuck trying to use the solver in matlab in a similar fashion I used the solver in excel.
My problem is as follows :

I have a 50x6 matrix (named TO) I need to minimize as much as possible (the goal would be 0). This matrix is the result of function f, in which MO is the matrix that has to change to reach the goal.

So far, I've tried using **fgoalattain** and here is the code I wrote :

```
h = @(MO)f(A,B,alpha,MO,OA,OB,50);

goal = zeros(50,6);

weight = ones(50,6);

[MO,fval] = fgoalattain(h,MO,goal,weight);
```

MO is the matrix that has to vary. It is of size 12x12.
I would like the result of my function f (TO) to be a matrix filled of values as close to 0 as possible.

When running the code, I obtain the following results :

```
Solver stopped prematurely.

fgoalattain stopped because it exceeded the function evaluation limit,
options.MaxFunEvals = 14500 (the default value).
```

I tried using options to increase the number of iterations but to no avail :

```
options = optimset('Display','iter','Algorithm','interior-point','MaxIter',5000000,'MaxFunEvals',5000000);
[MO,fval] = fgoalattain(h,MO,goal,weight,[],[],[],[],[],[],[],options);
```

I am getting lost using the solver, it is very different from the one I used in excel, and I'm still new to matlab. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you !

Comment: I think you would have an easier time using [`fmincon`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html?searchHighlight=fmincon)? It's a lot easier to minimize something than to make it match a number (`0` in your case). Can we see your function `f`? What you have so far looks generally correct so I would just alter `f` so that it outputs the absolute sum of the elements of the current output matrix and then minimizing that scalar is basically the same as trying to force each element to equal zero.

Comment: Would you post more info to let us reproduce the error?